# How to extract addresses in PHP, from a source with no standard format of writing addresses?

Tags: php, extract

I have a bunch of messages (from twitter) that include addresses. They are in various kinds (as many as you could imagine a random sampling of people enter an address. The city location is always known so they normally just put a road name and number/area)

Is there any library out there to extract these? I've tried looking but found nothing.

If no, any suggestions as to how I do this? At the moment I am just extracting things like [previous word + [rd/ave/street/lane/blvd]] but it isn't that accurate.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know of no library that does this.. but a crazy idea came to mind while reading your question.

Use the google maps geocoding api to find long and lat for your address..
then use the reverse geocoding api to find the address from your lat and long since it will be neatly formatted in a json object.

Quite messy but it is the best i can come up with. (Has the upside that you then already have the coordinates of your address :)

Comment: i suppose this could work. I take it you are assuming that google will be able to process a roughly written address?

Comment: they can because they have a rather large database of streetnames, cities, etc all linked and referenced with each other.. should be the same algo used for the search field at maps.google.com.. so go ahead and test it